# JSF 2.0: Validate equality of 2 InputSecret Fields (confirm password) without writing Code?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm developing a pure JavaEE6 application with JSF 2.0 and Glassfish.
My JSF implementation is Primefaces (beside Mojarra provided by Glassfish).

I want to verify if the values of 2 password fields in a JSF form are equal.
With Seam, there is the neat component `<s:validateEquality for="pw1"/>`.
I want do to the same without Seam, just using JSF (or maybe a component of a JSF library). Until now i only saw examples which validate the form with a custom validator. But i would like to compare the fields without writing Java code or Javascript code.
Is that possible?

This what it looks like with Seam:

```
...
<h:inputSecret id="passwort" value="#{personHome.instance.password}" 
    redisplay="true" required="true">
  <f:validateLength minimum="8"/>
  <a:support event="onblur" reRender="passwortField" bypassUpdates="true" ajaxSingle="true" />
</h:inputSecret>
...    
<h:inputSecret id="passwort2" required="true" redisplay="true">
  <!-- find the JSF2.0-equivalent to this tag: -->
  <s:validateEquality for="passwort"/>
  <a:support event="onblur" reRender="passwort2Field" bypassUpdates="true" ajaxSingle="true" />
</h:inputSecret>
...
```

Comment: so... if there is no solution 'without' code, what is the cleanest solution 'with' code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way i finally did it, which i like cause it's short and easy. The only problem is that it's not really re-usable, but as i only need this in one case, i rather save some LOCs and do it this way.
Snippet from my view:

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{personHome.person.password}">
  <f:ajax event="blur" render="passwordError" />
</h:inputSecret> 
<h:message for="password" errorClass="invalid" id="passwordError" />

<h:inputSecret id="password2" validator="#{personHome.validateSamePassword}">
  <f:ajax event="blur" render="password2Error" />
</h:inputSecret> 
<h:message for="password2" errorClass="invalid" id="password2Error" />
```

My Backing Bean (just the important part):

```
@Named @ConversationScoped
public class PersonHome {
  private Person person;

  public Person getPerson() {
    if (person == null) return new Person();
    else return person;
  }

  public void validateSamePassword(context:FacesContext, toValidate:UIComponent, value:Object) {
    String confirmPassword = (String)value;
    if (!confirmPassword.equals(person.getPassword()) {
      FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Passwords do not match!", "Passwords do not match!")
      throw new Validatorexception(message);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You may use Primefaces  tag in this very simple way:

```
<p:password id="password" value="#{bean.password}" match="repeated_password" />

<p:password id="repeated_password" value="#{bean.password}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Seam3 Faces module](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/FacesModule) will support "Cross-field form validation" in it's imminent Alpha3 release.  This is your best bet for a minimal code solution, see this [blog](http://ocpsoft.com/java/jsf-2-0-cross-field-form-validation-simpl-in-reality/) for a howto.

Alternatively I've done this programmatically by using the f:attribute tag to pass the clientId of another form field to a custom validator, then using the UIComponent passed into the custom validator to access the other filed by id.

Here's the facelet file:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Enter your email address" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.registration.subRegistration}" />
<h:inputText label="Email" id="textEmail1" value="#{cc.attrs.registration.email}" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.registration.subRegistration}" required="true" maxlength="128" size="35"></h:inputText>
<h:message for="textEmail1" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.registration.subRegistration}"></h:message>

<h:outputLabel value="Re-enter your email address confirmation:" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.registration.subRegistration and cc.attrs.duplicateEmailRequired}" />
<h:inputText label="Email repeat" id="textEmail2" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.registration.subRegistration and cc.attrs.duplicateEmailRequired}" maxlength="64" size="35">
    <f:validator validatorId="duplicateFieldValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="field1Id" value="#{component.parent.parent.clientId}:textEmail1" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="textEmail2" rendered="#{!cc.attrs.registration.subRegistration and cc.attrs.duplicateEmailRequired}"></h:message>
```

Here's the validator class:

```
package ca.triumf.mis.trevents.jsf.validator;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator(value="duplicateFieldValidator")
public class DuplicateFieldValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException {
    // Obtain the client ID of the first field from f:attribute.
    System.out.println(component.getFamily());
    String field1Id = (String) component.getAttributes().get("field1Id");

    // Find the actual JSF component for the client ID.
    UIInput textInput = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent(field1Id);
    if (textInput == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unable to find component with id %s",field1Id));
    // Get its value, the entered text of the first field.
    String field1 = (String) textInput.getValue();

    // Cast the value of the entered text of the second field back to String.
    String confirm = (String) value;

    // Check if the first text is actually entered and compare it with second text.
    if (field1 != null && field1.length() != 0 && !field1.equals(confirm)) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("E-mail addresses are not equal."));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to use a mixture of both answers to succeed.

I used ifischers short solution but my bean password field was null.

So I used the lines from Brian Leathem to get the UIInput from the context:

```
public void passwordValidator(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {

    UIInput passwordField = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("registerForm:password");
    if (passwordField == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unable to find component."));
    String password = (String) passwordField.getValue();
    String confirmPassword = (String) value;
    if (!confirmPassword.equals(password)) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Passwords do not match!", "Passwords do not match!");
        throw new ValidatorException(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you could use [`<o:validateEqual>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual). It also allows setting a custom message. The [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual) has a live example demonstrating the common usecase of validating the password confirmation. You don't even need ajax to update the model before invoking the validator (as [your own approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973427/) does).

Here's the minimum necessary code:

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{personHome.person.password}" />
<h:message for="password" />

<h:inputSecret id="password2" />
<h:message for="password2" />

<o:validateEqual components="password password2" 
    message="Passwords do not match!" showMessageFor="password2" />
```

No Java code needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with Apache MyFaces ExtVal.

Answer (score -1):

Without solution, I was forced to do the validation in a ugly way (not recommended). At least it works till I found better solution.

In the method that returns the action, I check both values, in case of different values, I add error messages on context and return null to the navigation handler.

```
package com.jsf.beans.user;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputSecret;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import com.pichler.jsf.beans.base.JsfViewBean;

 @ManagedBean(name = "changePassword")
 @RequestScoped
 public class ChangePassword extends JsfViewBean {
private HtmlInputSecret inputSecret1, inputSecret2;

/**
 * @return the inputSecret1
 */
public HtmlInputSecret getInputSecret1() {
    return inputSecret1;
}

/**
 * @param inputSecret1
 *            the inputSecret1 to set
 */
public void setInputSecret1(HtmlInputSecret inputSecret1) {
    this.inputSecret1 = inputSecret1;
}

/**
 * @return the inputSecret2
 */
public HtmlInputSecret getInputSecret2() {
    return inputSecret2;
}

/**
 * @param inputSecret2
 *            the inputSecret2 to set
 */
public void setInputSecret2(HtmlInputSecret inputSecret2) {
    this.inputSecret2 = inputSecret2;
}

private String password1, password2;

public String alterar() {
    if (!StringUtils.equals(password1, password2)) {
        addErrorMessage(inputSecret1.getClientId(),
                "As senhas não coincidem");
        addErrorMessage(inputSecret2.getClientId(),
                "As senhas não coincidem");
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @return the password1
 */
public String getPassword1() {
    return password1;
}

/**
 * @param password1
 *            the password1 to set
 */
public void setPassword1(String password1) {
    this.password1 = password1;
}

/**
 * @return the password2
 */
public String getPassword2() {
    return password2;
}

/**
 * @param password2
 *            the password2 to set
 */
public void setPassword2(String password2) {
    this.password2 = password2;
}
```

}

*JsfViewBean is just a class that has some common methods, as "addMessages".