# JSF XHTML Registration Form Password Check

Tags: forms, validation, jsf, xhtml, passwords

Im trying to create a Registartion form but i need the user to select and put their password in, then confirm their password.

How would i implement a check to see if these match and if they do stroe them in a RegsisteredBean.java file in a variable.

Im a complete beginner with JSF and XHTML.

Thanks

Comment: interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909021/jsf-2-0-validate-equality-of-2-inputsecret-fields-confirm-password-without-wr & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489893/how-validate-two-password-fields-by-ajax

Comment: I had seen these and others but did not undertand them

Comment: You could just take on Primefaces and use the password component http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/password.jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and quick solution is actually done using the primefaces component as below (using the match attribute):

```
<h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />  
<p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordBean.password5}" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true"/>  

<h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />  
<p:password id="pwd2" value="#{passwordBean.password5}" label="Password 2" required="true"/>
```

Here's a [link to the official showcase examples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/password.xhtml).